# Error while Publishing web app

Tags: asp.net

I got this error message while trying to publish my asp.net web app :

```
Copying file packages\Newtonsoft.Json.6.0.4\lib\portable-net40+sl5+wp80+win8+wpa81\Newtonsoft.Json.dll to C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\2\WebSitePublish\Results-69221645\obj\Debug\Package\PackageTmp\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.6.0.4\lib\portable-net40+sl5+wp80+win8+wpa81\Newtonsoft.Json.dll failed. Could not find a part of the path 'packages\Newtonsoft.Json.6.0.4\lib\portable-net40+sl5+wp80+win8+wpa81\Newtonsoft.Json.dll'
```

please help me to recover this issue

Comment: You have a problem with a reference to your project, what does it have to do with Sql Server ?

Comment: this has nothing to do with SQL Server - don't add irrelevant tags. Just because your app might use SQL Server doesn't mean it's part of the question. Anyway it looks like you have a missing DLL file. Try re-installing the NuGet package.